# R: How to manipulate textfile data to erase specific lines

Tags: r

I have a textfile that contains lines of data like this:
fSumw[0] = 0, x=-0.5, error=0

I want to manipulate the datafile to only leave the numeric entries like this:
0, -0.5, 0

what would be the best way to approach this in R?
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions. Given a text object `txt`, do the following:

```
txt <- 'fSumw[0] = 0, x=-0.5, error=0'
regmatches(txt, gregexpr('(?<==)\\s*-*\\d+\\.*\\d*', txt, perl = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] " 0"   "-0.5" "0"
```

The `gregexpr` function returns the position of any string matching the specified pattern (given as a regular expression) and `regmatches` returns these matches by searching the position in the `txt` object.

For more guidance on regular expressions you can download the cheat sheet:
https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf